# Haskell - fmap and foldMap for Tree

Tags: haskell

im new to haskell and im a bit stuck i have

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
    deriving (Show)
```

I want to crate an fmap and a foldMap , so i tried

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
    fmap f (Branch a left right) = Branch a (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

and it simply doesn't work and i don't understand why , i'm pretty sure the problem is here

```
.. = Branch a (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

anyway i could really use some help  for the fmap and foldMap ,actually i have an idea but i don't have the right syntax.

thanks for the help.

Comment: You did not define the empty case, nor did you apply `f` on `a` for the `Branch` case.

Comment: For future questions: usually it is advisable to copy paste the exact compiler message. By looking at the message, you can usually already get a good idea what is wrong.

Comment: By the way, GHC can now derive `Functor` instances as well, if you require `deriving (....,Functor)` and enable a GHC extension. It is still a good beginner exercise to code such instances by hand, since that will make you more familiar with the behavior of `fmap` for your functors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are forgetting to apply the function `f` on the `a`s contained in the `Branch` nodes as well, otherwise you only apply the function on the leaves. Moreover, you are forgetting a case for the `Empty` constructor.

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f Empty = Empty
  fmap f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
  fmap f (Branch a left right) = Branch (f a) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, I think that your data declaration maybe isn't quite right (or rather is not standard). 
 Typically one defines

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

That is, a `Tree` is either an empty node (`Nil`), or a `Node` that contains a value and two subtrees.  In this way, you can represent a nonempty tree with no branches as `Node a Nil Nil`.

Anyway, to properly define the `Functor` instance for this type (the instance for your `Tree` type is similar), you need to define `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b` for the all the possible values of type `Tree a` -- in this case, the empty value and the nonempty value.  You're on the right track with your implementation, but you forgot to apply `f` to the value contained in the nonempty node:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap _ Nil = Nil -- nothing to fmap in this case
  fmap f (Node a left right) = Node (f a) (fmap f left) (fmap f right)
```

Comment: I can imagine a use for distinguishing between `Leaf x` and `Branch x Empty Empty`; the former may not be converted to an interior node by an `insert` function, while the latter may. It depends on what you want to model. At best, I would put the alternate definition at the end of the answer, or omit it altogether.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough.